# Sqlite - trim to the right of the last instance of a character

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to join data from two different sources by names. One source displays names as "Donald John Trump" while the other displays "John Trump D.".

I solved that issue by substr(name,1,instr(name,'.')-3) on the latter and using the result (i.e. John Trump) to match using the like-function.

The problem is that sometimes the name can be displayed as "John Trump Do.", so the "-3" doesn't work in that case. I thus need a way to trim to the right of the last instance of space.